# How can I make a set of numbers increase every second and for each increment, print the current set on a new line?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, timer, countdowntimer

I have these set of 11 numbers that increase per second, but I want each increment or the current set of numbers to write on a new line. E.g;

20220215155

20220215156

20220215157 etc...

I tried adding the n tag buh it returned an error.

```
var i = 20220215155
    function increment() {
    i+, + </n>;

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = i
     }
  ('increment()', 1000);
```

Please I really need help as I have been trying to get this for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid JS

Here is something that does work - I am using setInterval here

```js
var i = 20220215155

function increment() {
  i++; // increment
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += i + "<br/>"; // add it with a breakline
}
setInterval(increment, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

You can use a template literal for the string too

```
`${i}<br/>`
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please add html and css ti your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to call the function after a set time while also increasing the number you initially pass into the function.

```js
// Cache the element
const test = document.querySelector('#test');

let n = 20220215155;

// `increment` accepts `n` as an argument
function increment(n) {

  // Add a new HTML string to the element
  test.innerHTML += `${n}</br>`;

  // Call the function again with an new `n`
  setTimeout(increment, 1000, ++n);
}

increment(n);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)